# How to force process to work in the background even if it refuses to?

Tags: background-process

As an example:

```
$ vim &
[1] 19133
$ bg
[1]+ vim &

[1]+  Stopped                 vim
$
```

However, I do not want vim to stop when put in the background. Is that possible? (applies for other programs such as login and telnet too)

Comment: Whats the point of sending an interactive editor in the background and expected it to work in the background? its not clear..you can just use `fg %1` (assuming the jon number is 1) to resume editing in the foreground..

Answer (score 1):

Interactive processes that are sent to the background are suspended when they try to read input from the terminal. You can use a terminal multiplexer such as `screen`

`screen -d -m vim`

This create a new screen session and automatically detaches it.
Use `screen -r` to reattach to it.

Comment: I keep getting `Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/1' - please check.` when doing `screen -r`.

Comment: Nevermind, it was something regarding my SSH connection. Ignore the comment above please.

Comment: By the way, how can I send input to a detached screen without attaching it?

Comment: @tildearrow, unfortunately I don't know. This seems like a really nice question to ask in this site, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know whether it is right or wrong if we do

```
ping google.com &
```

than it is still running but if we do

```
cat >abc.txt &
```

it is not running.Reason for this may be the process which is interactive is stopped because yo can do any thing when these process is in background so save resources